# Inserting multiple rows in a table

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot

I  am creating a registration form and I have problem in inserting multiple rows in a table from a file in **Itelij** named **roles.sql**. I have selected PostgreSQL as a database. 
The query looks good at first glance and I don't know where is the problem.

```
INSERT INTO public.roles (name) VALUES ('ROLE_USER'), ('ROLE_ADMIN');
```

I have configured the program in a file named **application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/testdb?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL= DEBUG

## App Properties
app.jwtSecret= JWTSuperSecretKey
app.jwtExpirationInMs = 604800000

## Jackson Properties
spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS= false
spring.jackson.time-zone= UTC
```

This is the code that makes the registration in a class named AuthController

```
// Creating user's account
User user = new User(signUpRequest.getName(), signUpRequest.getUsername(),
        signUpRequest.getEmail(), signUpRequest.getPassword());

user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));

Role userRole = roleRepository.findByName(RoleName.ROLE_USER)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new AppException("User Role not set."));

user.setRoles(Collections.singleton(userRole));

User result = userRepository.save(user);

URI location = ServletUriComponentsBuilder
        .fromCurrentContextPath().path("/api/users/{username}")
        .buildAndExpand(result.getUsername()).toUri();

return ResponseEntity.created(location).body(new ApiResponse(true, "User registered successfully"));
```

I try to register a user using **Postman** and as a response gives in picture below that sat

```
{
  "timestamp": "2018-11-26T14:10:20.833+0000",
  "status": 500,
  "error": "Internal Server Error",
  "message": "User Role not set.",
  "path": "/api/auth/signup"
}
```

Please can someone explain me where stands the problem of not inserting the rows in database? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is `roles.sql` being executed? Do you see that happen in the logs when spring boot starts? Or else, how are you running the script? Is it in `src/main/resources`? I've called scripts like that `data.sql` in the past. I'm not sure what names spring recognizes. What happens if you connect to the database and do `SELECT * FROM public.roles;`?

Comment: Yes it is roles.sql and it is in src/main/resources. Yes I have called the upon script to create to rows in roles table but are not created when I run the Spring boot application, only if I execute the query, but when I run again the spring boot, the rows that are registered from the query execution are loosed.